# Save tmux daily history

Tags: bash, shell, tmux, history

I'll often run things for days inside tmux session, and I like to save my bash history daily (I use logrotate). I do not exit tmux session unless necessary. Could I somehow save my tmux history for that day without exiting the session, on a daily basis, maybe force tmux to write to .bash_history without exiting the session?

I tried `:save-buffer /home/me/tmux-hist.txt` but that only seems to save last command?

Comment: tmux history and bash history are 2 different things. please elaborate your real requirement.

Comment: Your question pertains more to other stack site like SuperUser, as it is meant to ask advanced usage of an administrative console tool `tmux` rather than code related.

Comment: I just realized that save-buffer saves the copy buffer, not history buffer. If I do "history" within one of the tmux screens I get only it's (correct) history, but "cat ~/bash_history" does not produce the same result. bash_history is written upon exit from session. Also history buffer is different for each screen/pane. I'd want to save daily history from all of the panes, without exiting/closing the session.

Comment: @LéaGris Wouldn't a script (or oneliner) running via a cron job to do something like this qualify? I already have logrotate there running daily to save bash_history.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this question was for this forum, but I managed to solve it, so here is the solution:

This is not a tmux issue, but rather shell/bash "issue". Adding this to .bashrc:

```
## Issues with tmux history
# avoid duplicates..
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups
# append history entries:
shopt -s histappend
# After each command, save and reload history:
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -n; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

This way commands run in tmux window/pane are added in the history immediately. If you run "echo 1" in pane 1 and then "echo 2" in pane 2 you will see "echo 1" in pane 2 history as well.
Daily history is then saved via logrotate.